# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on waitForExpectations while unit testing

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, xctest, weak-references

Consider the following, simplified structure:

```
class MyClass {
    weak var delegate: MyClassDelegate?
}

protocol MyClassDelegate: class {
    func goneWrong()
}
```

And the test case that throws the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (0x40dedeadbec0) error:

```
class MyTest: XCTestCase {
    func test() {
        let exp = expectation(description: "Expecting a call")
        let a = MyClass()
        a.delegate = MyMockDelegate(exp: exp)

        // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x40dedeadbec0)
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10)
    }

    class MyMockDelegate: MyClassDelegate {
        let exp: XCTestExpectation

        init(exp: XCTestExpectation) {
            self.exp = exp
        }

        func goneWrong() {
            self.exp.fulfill()
        }
    }
}
```

The error is not thrown if the delegate var is declared normally, without the weak keyword. The problem is that it needs to be weak to avoid the strong reference cycle in the real code (not the test case). How do I go around this?

Comment: Just save your delegate-mock in a constant to maintain a strong reference in the current lexical scope: `let delegate = MyMockDelegate(exp: exp)`

Comment: I have noticed this also tends to occur in Xcode Playgrounds when delegates are declared weakly.

Comment: @werediver I've tried it, I've also tried to store it as a property of the test class but I get the same error.

Comment: Unable to reproduce from example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm sure you solved it by now, but for the sake of future readers, the problem is that you've defined your delegate to be `weak` (i.e. allow it to be set to `nil` and the object deallocated as soon as their are no strong references). But you have no strong references to your `MyMockDelegate` instance:

```
let a = MyClass()
a.delegate = MyMockDelegate(exp: exp)
```

Now, I'd expect it to gracefully `nil` the `delegate` reference in this scenario, and I don't know why you got error at `0x40dedeadbec0` address, because I don't. (BTW, I don't think `0x40dedeadbec0` is a real memory address, but rather is one of those bad puns by some kernel developer.)

Anyway, if you expect your mock delegate to work, you need to keep a reference to it until the end of your test, e.g.:

```
class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {

    func test() {
        let exp = expectation(description: "Expecting a call")

        var delegate: MyMockDelegate? = MyMockDelegate(exp: exp)

        let a = MyClass()
        a.delegate = delegate

        // do something

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10)

        delegate = nil
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a property in your test class to keep a strong reference to the delegate for the life of the test. Either way, you need more than a single `weak` reference if you don't want that disappearing on you.

Comment: BTW, does anyone know what `0x40dedeadbec0` means? This address looks suspiciously like those pun-laiden exception codes (e.g., "0xbad22222" = failed for VOIP trying too ("2") often; 0x8badf00d = "ate bad food" when watchdog process kills your app; etc.), but I don't see a reference to it anywhere. And this value, `0x40dedeadbec0` shows up too frequently as a result of memory problems so I'm guessing it's someone's idea of a good pun, but I can't find a definition of it anywhere...

Comment: E.g. I'm guessing something like "(fill in the blank) dead because" or "(fill in the blank) dead became zero", but don't know what "40de" stands for...